# Cannot Deploy App To WildFly 8 On OpenShift

Tags: java, openshift, wildfly, wildfly-8

I created an OpenShift application online, using the Wildfly 8 cartridge, and also added MySQL 5.5 and PHPMyAdmin 4.0 to the app. Its on a small gear on a free account so it only has 1GB storage and 512MB memory.

I disabled automatic maven build so I can deploy by simply placing my packaged ROOT.war file under the deployments folderand executing git push.

However, running git push has been failing to successfully deploy the app and the logs on the server (am tailing files with JBoss Dev Studio 8) show some sort of error when trying to start Wildfly 8, caused by a  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException saying  :

> Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.cmp' is not supported on servers
>   running this version. The extension is only supported for use by hosts
>   running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain

I don't really know what is going on, and need help with resolving the issue. I have a past of the logs here : http://ur1.ca/i8a7s

Comment: Is the org.jboss.as.cmp package something you are referring to in your code?  Have you tried removing it or not using it?

Comment: Does this app work on local WildFly ?

Is the WildFly custom configured in any way as well ? Or are you using stock cartridge ?

Comment: Are you including a CMP bean in your archive ? Support for CMP was removed from WildFly 8.0 Alpha 1: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-525

Comment: Yes, I am using the stock WildFly cartridge on OpenShift. I am not directly using anything from org.jboss.as.cmp, but my app uses Errai, CDI, Hibernate, Bean Validation and other standard JavaEE technologies. I don't know if any of these make use of code from the org.jboss.as.cmp. Deploying to local wildfly 8.0.0 fails due to an exception caused by :  org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-001407: Cannot declare an injection point with a type variable: [BackedAnnotatedField. I was told WELD fixed this in the new WildFly, so am downloading it, but expect it to work on OpenShift.

Comment: I finally downloaded WildFly-8.1.0.Final and tried to deploy the app to it but with the same DefinitionException which I have pasted here : http://ur1.ca/i8fdd I however don't have these errors with EAP, but EAP on OpenShift is not free so I am kinda stock with WildFly which is failing for my app (with different errors) both locally and in OpenShift online.

Comment: Since this is not JUST an openshift issue, it would be worth updating the tags on your question to include other things such as, java, wildfly, etc, also, you should include the correct information in the original post that you have added into your comments below it, so people can find it more easily.